# .bat file executing itself over and over

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wrote 
ping google.fr -n 2500 
in a .txt file, saved as "ping.bat".
When I execute this script, I can see that the command execut itselfs over and over, as if it was into a loop. Ofc I didn't wrote any loop in the txt file.
Does anyone got a solution?

(check picture for more details)
Normal expected behave of the command :http://prntscr.com/cl2z44
Actual behave : [Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtDIb.png)

Comment: Do you know what the `-n` option to `ping` does?

Comment: Yep, it repeats the command the number you want it to.

Comment: So it may explain why you see the command run 2500 times, don't you think?

Comment: Check the picture, you'll understand what I mean. Normal behave of the commande should be : http://prntscr.com/cl2z44

Comment: The batch file is calling itself because it has the same name as the ping utility. Change its name or write `ping.exe google.fr -n 2500`.

Comment: Already tried to rename it google.bat, didn't fix the problem. ping.exe google.fr -n 25000 fixed the problem, thx a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Preferably, save the script using another name. Otherwise, `ping google.fr -n 2500` would execute itself (`ping.bat`) in current directory rather than searching `ping.exe` in `PATH` variable. For proof, try `where ping`.

Another approach (nonpreferable): keep `ping.bat` name but specify `ping.EXE google.fr -n 2500` inside your bat script.

Comment: Thx a lot for the explaination.